# Unknow column 'ColumnName' in ON clause

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I' am using SQLAlchemy, and I have the following error in the generated SQL query. I have the table `relaciones_laborales` that need to join with two tables `funciones_relacion_laboral` with the field `RelLabId` and `puestos` with the field `PuestoId`.

```
join=(relaciones_laborales.join(
    funciones_relacion_laboral.join(
        funciones_asignadas.join(
            sillas.join(
                silla_grupo_materia.join(
                    puestos, (relaciones_laborales.c.PuestoId ==
                              puestos.c.PuestoId)),
                sillas.c.SillaId == silla_grupo_materia.c.SillaId,
                isouter=True),
            sillas.c.SillaId == funciones_asignadas.c.SillaId),
        (funciones_asignadas.c.FuncAsignadaId ==
         funciones_relacion_laboral.c.FuncAsignadaId)),
    relaciones_laborales.c.RelLabId == funciones_relacion_laboral.c.RelLabId))
```

Then I construct the query with

```
query = sa.select(...).select_from(join)
```

I obtain the following error:

```
1054, u"Unknown column 'RELACIONES_LABORALES.PuestoId' in 'on clause'"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For sake of clarity let's use a little easier example. Given tables *x*, *y*, and *z*:

```
x, y, z = [Table(t, metadata, Column('i', Integer))
           for t in ['x', 'y', 'z']]
```

A statement such as

```
j = x.join(y.join(z, x.c.i == z.c.i), y.c.i == x.c.i)
```

produces an SQL expression object that compiles to

```
x JOIN (y JOIN z ON x.i = z.i) ON y.i = x.i
```

since the innermost expression is evaluated first, passed on as the argument to the enclosing function call, and so on. The join in brackets takes precedence, but there is no table *x* visible at that point. If on the other hand you change the way you form the join a bit and chain them:

```
j = x.\
    join(y, y.c.i == x.c.i).\
    join(z, z.c.i == x.c.i)
```

you get

```
x JOIN y ON y.i = x.i JOIN z ON z.i = x.i
```

which is probably what you were after. So with that in mind:

```
join = (
    relaciones_laborales.

    join(funciones_relacion_laboral,
         relaciones_laborales.c.RelLabId ==
         funciones_relacion_laboral.c.RelLabId).

    join(funciones_asignadas,
         funciones_asignadas.c.FuncAsignadaId ==
         funciones_relacion_laboral.c.FuncAsignadaId).

    join(sillas,
         sillas.c.SillaId == funciones_asignadas.c.SillaId).

    join(silla_grupo_materia,
         sillas.c.SillaId == silla_grupo_materia.c.SillaId,
         isouter=True).

    join(puestos,
         relaciones_laborales.c.PuestoId == puestos.c.PuestoId)
)
```

Comment: I append the join with puestos after to the last end parenthesis and worked well because puestos join with the result table of the others joins. Thanks, I think that your solution is better.